# kotlinx advanced deserialization to change object structure

Tags: json, kotlin, kotlinx.serialization

using kotlinx and given a JSON input like `{"a": 123, "b": "foo", "c": false}`, is there a smart way to have this deserialized into a POJO where the property values contain the original value and the respective serial name of the property?

```kotlin
@Serializable
class Slot<T>(val name: String, val value: T)

@Serializable
class Slots(
  @SerialName("a")
  propertyA: Slot<Integer?>? = null,
  @SerialName("b")
  propertyB: Slot<String?>? = null,
  @SerialName("c")
  propertyC: Slot<Boolean?>? = null
)
```

So the resulting object in Kotlin would effectively look like this: `{ propertyA={name="a", value=123}, propertyB={name="b", value="foo"}, propertyC={name="c", value=false} }`.

I can't seem to find anything appropriate in the kotlinx docs but might be overlooking something.

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to simply parse your JSON object as a `Map<String, Any>`? This way you don't need a custom serialization setup and are more flexible on regards to the amount of slots required. If you want to make user of your `Slots` class, you still could convert the Map entries into an `Slots` object.

Comment: @Endzeit I had tried that and it would've been sufficient for my purposes but as far as I found out you cannot deserialize to `Any` using kotlinx. `JsonElement` should be the type to use. However, it is really cumbersome to work with, imho.

Comment: Do you need the  `propertyA`, `propertyB`, etc.? Otherwise, `JsonElement` is indeed the way to go. The reason it may be a bit more cumbersome to use is because it supports the full JSON spec (lists/primitives). If you aren't interested in those and want more type safety (e.g., you never expect lists in `value`), you could likely implement a custom serializer. If you do, just go with `JsonElement` and add helper functions (they are already there afaik) where needed.

Comment: I ended up writing my own KSerializer that first decodes into a surrogate class that matches the request's structure and mapping that onto the desired structure described above. I was hoping to not have to manage such a mapping manually, but it's fine now. Something similar could of course be achieved using JsonElements as Steven suggested but I don't see a way around the mapping step atm.